# Is it possible to dynamically select a value (sheet name) from a data validated list and also dynamically load a value from that selected sheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I know that sounds fairly confusing, but lets say I have 32 different sheets and an extra sheet with a list of all of the sheet names. I make a data validated list of all of the sheet names with that list on the extra sheet. Is it possible to find a value on the selected sheet from that list?

For example, the validated list is in cell C2 and the value I want to select on each sheet is in cell D3.

Is there something like in Excel: 
='(C2)'!D3

I'm looking for something like string literals, but for excel cells essentially.

Comment: You can use `=INDIRECT("'"&C2&"'!D3")`

Answer (score 0):

Okay well I found this finally... Of course right after I asked the question, but here is the formula:

=INDIRECT("'"&C2&"'!D3")

Fun stuff...